dynamic conversion of Decimal(38,18)data type that converts from default decimal datatype in ADF
ADF copy activity by default converts decimal datatype to decimal(38,18) , how can I overcome it to use original datatype decimal as source for multiple tables dynamically with different schemas for all the tables in source.
CAN SOMEONE GIVE ME A SOLUTION, HOW TO RESOLVE THIS IN ADF WHILE COPYING DYNAMICALLY FROM HANA SOURCE TO ADLS GEN2?
NOTE: THERE ARE 200 TABLES IN HANA SOURCE AND ALL ARE WITH DIFFERENT SCHEMAS
previously I did this by changing data types manually as original decimal for small number of tables in synapse database , but in my current project source is same but tables are lot . so someone from the community can give a solution how to implement with screenshots if possible .

Writing in capitals is seen a shouting. Please do not shout, it is considered rude.

To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

@NaveenSharma Hi, there is no error I'm getting the solution i tried is for one table using databricks but I want to make it dynamic for multiple tables , I have tried with data flows using cast function on decimal columns but I couldn't make it dynamic as well, I wonder no one faced this issue in the community when working in migration projects

Are you trying to create table automatically through ADF?


When table is dynamically created in sink by using auto create sink table option in ADF, this could happen.
Auto create table infers the data types from the source data itself and create the table automatically.
It will not take the same data source as source and assign it to the sink. Because source and sink are of two different datastores. There can be of different datatypes between those two data stores itself.
Thus, it is recommended to create the table manually once in the sink with the same column name as in source. This would automatically map the source and sink columns in ADF copy activity.

